How to best pass machine learning models in FastAPI to endpoints on different routers?
I have a FastAPI application I want to serve the same ML model across different endpoints (prompts and input processing etc. varies).
now in my (root) app.py file I have something like:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

from api.routers.subrouter1 import router as sr1
from api.routers.subrouter2 import router as sr2

app = FastAPI()

@app.on_event("startup")
def load_model(model_tag:str):
    app.state.model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_tag)
    app.state.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_tag)


app.include_router(sr1, prefix="/sr1")
app.include_router(sr2, prefix="/sr2")

All the loading works, but where I run into trouble is when I want to access the models to do some inference.
the Subrouter 1 file looks something like this:
from fastapi import APIrouter

from api.models.subrouter1 import sr1Request

@router.post("/inference/")
def do_some_inference(request: sr1Request):
    model = request.app.state.model
    tokenizer = request.app.state.tokenizer
    results = some_ml_function(request, model, tokenizer)
    return results

This is the general idea of how the code is structured right now. Before, I was loading the model in app.py outside of any funtion and just assigned it to a global model/tokenizer object, but I also had all my endpoints there so they could reference it right away. Now with the app expanding I want neat little routers each containing their respective logic. Then I read that you can access the app state via starlette's Request object and that worked as well. However, now I also want to use pydantic's object validation.
Now, when I hit the endpoint and it parses the custom request object containing all my fields and validators it naturally no longer has access to the request.app.state.model attribute and I get an error.
What's the best way to load ML models only once in FastAPI and still be able to use custom request objects? It seems like a pretty ordinary use case and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

You can have both your pydantic model and the request object as arguments to your function: def do_some_inference(actual_body: sr1Model, request: Request): - the actual_body will be the JSON submitted validated against the pydantic model, while the request will be Starlette's metadata about the request. Is this what you're looking for?

Does this answer your question? Please have a look at this answer as well.

You should also find this answer helpful, with regard to submitting JSON data to a FastAPI endpoint.

Thank you @Chris, your linked topics were close, but I actually found a few other interesting topics in those (async multiple request handling for models etc) so thank you for that!

Create a reusable dependency that retrieves the model and tokenizer from the app state, so you don't have to repeatedly access request.app.state in every route handler.
so your root
from fastapi import FastAPI
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

from api.routers.subrouter1 import router as sr1
from api.routers.subrouter2 import router as sr2

app = FastAPI()

@app.on_event("startup")
def load_model():
    model_tag = "your-model-tag"  # Replace with your model identifier
    app.state.model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_tag)
    app.state.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_tag)

app.include_router(sr1, prefix="/sr1")
app.include_router(sr2, prefix="/sr2")

and create dependencies.py
from fastapi import Request, Depends

def get_model_and_tokenizer(request: Request):
    model = request.app.state.model
    tokenizer = request.app.state.tokenizer
    return model, tokenizer

then create subrouter1.py and it  will use the custom dependency to fetch the model and tokenizer and handle the request validation
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from api.models.subrouter1 import sr1Request
from api.dependencies import get_model_and_tokenizer

router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/inference/")
def do_some_inference(request_body: sr1Request, model_and_tokenizer: tuple = Depends(get_model_and_tokenizer)):
    model, tokenizer = model_and_tokenizer
    results = some_ml_function(request_body, model, tokenizer)
    return results


I tried that, but somehow I got errors with the tuple unpacking (with a tuple) or dict retrieval when I did the injection as a dict.
